# Selecionar apenas os dias de um Timestamp

Tags: postgresql

Preciso selecionar apenas os dias de uma subtração de datas, e se possível converter esse numero para `Integer`, será que isso é possível?

```
    SELECT 
    (select count(numeroserie) as  porcentagemTotal from public.lotesretornosuprimento where laudo = 'Garantia' and dataretornogarantia is not null),
    (select count(defeito) as porcentagemDef from public.lotesretornosuprimento t4 where t4.defeito = t2.defeito and t4.suprimento = t2.suprimento and laudo = 'Garantia' and dataretornogarantia is not null group by defeito, suprimento),
    (select count(fornecedor) as  porcentagemForn from public.lotesretornosuprimento t1 where t1.fornecedor = t2.fornecedor and laudo = 'Garantia' and dataretornogarantia is not null group by fornecedor),
    (select count(suprimento) as porcentagemSup from public.lotesretornosuprimento t3 where t3.suprimento = t2.suprimento and laudo = 'Garantia' and dataretornogarantia is not null group by suprimento),
    //Nessa linha
    (select SUM(dataretornogarantia - datasaidagarantia) as dataTotal from public.lotesretornosuprimento t5 where t5.suprimento = t2.suprimento and laudo = 'Garantia' and dataretornogarantia is not null group by suprimento),
    numeroserie, 
    suprimento, 
    fornecedor,  
    defeito,
    datasaidagarantia,
    dataretornogarantia
    FROM 
    public.lotesretornosuprimento t2 
    where 
    laudo = 'Garantia' and dataretornogarantia is not null
    order by fornecedor,suprimento,defeito,numeroserie
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podes usar [**DATE_PART()**](http://www.sqlines.com/postgresql/how-to/datediff), onde a estrutura seria `DATE_PART('day', dataFim - dataIni)`.

```
SELECT 
    (select count(numeroserie) as  porcentagemTotal from public.lotesretornosuprimento where laudo = 'Garantia' and dataretornogarantia is not null),
    (select count(defeito) as porcentagemDef from public.lotesretornosuprimento t4 where t4.defeito = t2.defeito and t4.suprimento = t2.suprimento and laudo = 'Garantia' and dataretornogarantia is not null group by defeito, suprimento),
    (select count(fornecedor) as  porcentagemForn from public.lotesretornosuprimento t1 where t1.fornecedor = t2.fornecedor and laudo = 'Garantia' and dataretornogarantia is not null group by fornecedor),
    (select count(suprimento) as porcentagemSup from public.lotesretornosuprimento t3 where t3.suprimento = t2.suprimento and laudo = 'Garantia' and dataretornogarantia is not null group by suprimento),
    //Nessa linha
    (select SUM(DATE_PART('day', dataretornogarantia - datasaidagarantia)) as dataTotal from public.lotesretornosuprimento t5 where t5.suprimento = t2.suprimento and laudo = 'Garantia' and dataretornogarantia is not null group by suprimento),
    numeroserie, 
    suprimento, 
    fornecedor,  
    defeito,
    datasaidagarantia,
    dataretornogarantia
FROM public.lotesretornosuprimento t2 
where laudo = 'Garantia'
  and dataretornogarantia is not null
order by fornecedor, suprimento, defeito, numeroserie
```

Comment: Dai para converter para integer é só fazer o Cast()?

Comment: Fiz alguns testes com o retorno e não precisou de conversão explícita pra o `SUM()`, funcionou de boa

Comment: Obrigado pela juda